# Regex to detect if words are part of the string and next word is not capitalized

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for a regex that would match a specific word or words which are part of the given string with a restriction - if there is a word after pattern this word should not be capitalized.
Let's assume that the words are '*Base Case*', so here are some examples

- `Final Base Case` - should match
- `Final Base Case financial` - should match
- `Final Base Case Financial` - should not match (the next word 'Financial' is capitalized)
- `Final Base Cases` - should not match ('Case' and 'Cases' are not matched)

I use the following regex to determine if my word/words are part of the string

```
\bBase Case(?!\w)
```

Can someone please help me modify my regex expression to add restriction for the next capitalized word?

Comment: try `\bBase Case\b (?![A-Z])` or `\bBase Case\b [^A-Z]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check for two cases after the search pattern:

1. end of string (`$`); or
2. another word, which doesn't begin with a capital letter (`\s+[^A-Z\s]`)

You can do that with this regex:

```
\bBase Case(?=$|\s+[^A-Z\s])
```

Note that since the second half of the lookahead asserts a space before the next word, it prevents `Base Cases` or similar from matching.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MxjdHI/2)

Comment: @CarySwoveland good catch! I didn't think of `'  '` matching `\s+[^A-Z]`. I've corrected the regex

Comment: `"Base Case."` doesn't match, but I don't know if it should.

Comment: @CarySwoveland agreed, it's unclear. There's no evidence of punctuation in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In a most generic case, you may use

```
\bBase\s+Case\b(?!\W*\p{Lu})
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbBase%5cs%2bCase%5cb%28%3f!%5cW*%5cp%7bLu%7d%29&i=Final+Base+Case%0d%0aFinal+Base+Case+financial%0d%0aFinal+Base+Case+Financial%0d%0aFinal+Base+Cases).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `Base\s+Case` - `Base`, 1+ whitespaces, `Case`
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!\W*\p{Lu})` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are 0 or more non-word chars followed with any Unicode uppercase letter immediately to the right of the current location.

If there is only whitespace expected between the word and the uppercase letter, replace `\W` with `\s`.

C# usage:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"\bBase\s+Case\b(?!\W*\p{Lu})")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Or, just to check if it exists in each string:

```
var texts = new List<string> {"Final Base Case", "Final Base Case financial", "Final Base Case Financial", "Final Base Cases"};
foreach (var text in texts) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", text, Regex.IsMatch(text, @"\bBase\s+Case\b(?!\W*\p{Lu})"));
}
```

See [C# demo](https://ideone.com/Pr1NB0). Output:

```
Final Base Case: True
Final Base Case financial: True
Final Base Case Financial: False
Final Base Cases: False
```